# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' : [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa-2.1

i am facing error while running the project that unable to build hibernate session factory

error on console

```
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.49
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 17 2019 18:45:30 UTC
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 8.5.49.0
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_66-b17
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\dolly.kumbhalkar\Documents\Dolly\Projects\AnySpaces\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\dolly.kumbhalkar\Documents\Dolly\Projects\AnySpaces\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\dolly.kumbhalkar\Documents\Dolly\Projects\AnySpaces\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\endorsed
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\dolly.kumbhalkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\dolly.kumbhalkar\Desktop;;.]
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:06 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2313 ms
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.49
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:07 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [108] milliseconds.
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:30 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2019-12-07 14:13:30.178 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started 
2019-12-07 14:13:30.849 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sat Dec 07 14:13:30 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy 
2019-12-07 14:13:31.152 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] 
2019-12-07 14:13:33.662 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0' 
2019-12-07 14:13:34.132 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3935 ms 
Dec 07, 2019 2:13:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'anyspace-dispatcher'
2019-12-07 14:13:34.171 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'anyspace-dispatcher': initialization started 
2019-12-07 14:13:34.191 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'anyspace-dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sat Dec 07 14:13:34 IST 2019]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext 
2019-12-07 14:13:34.193 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/anyspace-dispatcher-servlet.xml] 
2019-12-07 14:13:40.408 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'persistenceJPAConfig' of type [class in.techchefs.anyspace.common.data.configuration.PersistenceJPAConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe458096] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 
2019-12-07 14:13:40.814 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21496ae6] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying) 
2019-12-07 14:13:41.122 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
2019-12-07 14:13:41.898 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' 
2019-12-07 14:13:47.888 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in in.techchefs.anyspace.common.data.configuration.PersistenceJPAConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory 
2019-12-07 14:13:47.895 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in in.techchefs.anyspace.common.data.configuration.PersistenceJPAConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4885)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5199)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:884)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.getConnection(AbstractJdbcConnectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTable(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.getTableInformation(ImprovedDatabaseInformationImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.performMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:881)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
```

This is my JPA config class: PersistenceJPAConfig.java

```
package in.common.data.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.${env}.properties"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

    public static final String DB_MYSQL_DRIVER_PROPERTY = "database.mysql.driver-class";
    public static final String DB_MYSQL_HOST_PROPERTY = "database.mysql.host";
    public static final String DB_MYSQL_PORT_PROPERTY = "database.mysql.port";
    public static final String DB_MYSQL_DATABASE_PROPERTY = "database.mysql.database";
    public static final String DB_MYSQL_USERNAME_PROPERTY = "database.mysql.username";
    public static final String DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD_PROPERTY = "database.mysql.password";
    public static final String HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_PROPERTY = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    public static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT_PROPERTY = "hibernate.dialect";
    public static final String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_PROPERTY = "hibernate.show_sql";

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("in.techchefs.anyspace");
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());

        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty(DB_MYSQL_DRIVER_PROPERTY));
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://"+env.getProperty(DB_MYSQL_HOST_PROPERTY)+":"+env.getProperty(DB_MYSQL_PORT_PROPERTY)+"/"+env.getProperty(DB_MYSQL_DATABASE_PROPERTY));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty(DB_MYSQL_USERNAME_PROPERTY));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty(DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD_PROPERTY));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_PROPERTY, env.getProperty(HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_PROPERTY));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_PROPERTY, env.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_PROPERTY));
        properties.setProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_PROPERTY, env.getProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL_PROPERTY));

        return properties;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
database.mysql.driver-class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
database.mysql.host=localhost
database.mysql.port=3306
database.mysql.database=anyspace_dev_1504
database.mysql.username=root
database.mysql.password=root@123
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.ejb.use_class_enhancer=true
```

Here is pom.xml file i am using mysql server of 8.0.18 is there any reason of getting this error because i mention in dependency 5.1.28 but if i change that i got another error for import com.mysql.jdbc.StringUtils;

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>in.techchefs.anyspace</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>common</name>
    <description>Common for AnySpace</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>in.techchefs.anyspace</groupId>
        <artifactId>anyspace</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Framework dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For connection pooling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jfreechart -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jfree/jcommon -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>xero-java-mvn-repo</id>
            <url>https://raw.github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Java/mvn-repo/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!-- <repositories> <repository> <id>codelds</id> <url>https://code.lds.org/nexus/content/groups/main-repo</url> 
        </repository> </repositories> -->
    <build>
        <finalName>common</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-eclipse-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>${wtpversion}</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please update your pom.xml with dependency version numbers instead of configured property names.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the stack trace guides you quite well to the root cause.

You got an exception that tells you `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'`

Following the stack trace you can see it's `Caused by: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory`

Which is `Caused by: Unable to obtain JDBC Connection`

Which is `Caused by: Could not create connection to database server.`

So, at that point your problem isn't really that you can't create the entityManagerFactory bean, the problem is that your application can't connect to your database. So, you just have to check the connection to your database in the `application.properties` file. I hope this answers your question.